# local storage returning invalid format of date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angular-local-storage

```
 $localStorage.doctorDateTime.push({                            
    fullDate : new Date(doctorDateTime)
    });
```

I passed date string in new Date and then save it to local storage but when i retrieve it from local storage it showing me this format:

```
2015-01-01T13:41:18.300Z
```

while if console.log(doctorDateTime). it is showing right date string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

localStorage stored data are **strings only**. If you are trying to store something that is not string type, an implicit type coercion is taken place.

However, it looks like depending on some lib implementation you are using, because what you got behaves like [**`Date.prototype.toISOString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), while following code behaves like [**`Date.prototype.toString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString):

```
localStorage.setItem("fullDate", new Date(doctorDateTime));
```

You'd better explicitly convert the `Date` object to a string in your desired format before set to localStorage.

But, you could still get the `Date` object back with the [**ISO time string**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
var str = '2015-01-01T13:41:18.300Z';
var time = new Date(str); // you got the object back!
```

Comment: how to store date as date obj

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan although you can't store objects, you could still get the object back with that time string, see last part of my updated answer.

Comment: accepted but have to do more code to show it using ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

That's what happens when you do `( new Date() ).toString()`, it's the string representation of the date as it's converted to a string when stored in Local Storage.

Store the timestamp instead, it's a number representing milliseconds from epoch, and not an object

```
$localStorage.doctorDateTime.push({                            
    fullDate : ( new Date(doctorDateTime) ).getTime()
});
```

**Local Storage's functionality is limited to handle only string key/value pairs.**
Some browser will store objects, but it's not something you can rely on, you should be storing strings.  The easiest would be to store the timestamp, and then run that timestamp through `new Date` when you get it from Local Storage to get a date object.

Comment: i want to save date as date cause i have retrieve it as date not string. And on that string i have to use orderBy

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - maybe I wasn't clear enough, you can't!

Comment: It's not `toString`, the string format OP provides is produced by `toISOString`. Looks like it's depending on some lib implementation he's using.

Comment: @Leo - indeed it is, but it doesn't really matter for this, as it's the wrong approach regardless of what the string ends up looking like

Answer (score 0):

If you pass object to localstorage it will first do **JSON.stringify of your object** and then store it to local storage. So when next time you retrieve it, it will give you string value of date object. Try to do JSON.stringify(new Date()) you will have your date string. This is same string you are getting when you fetch next time.

**Best solution is convert your date to timestap when you store it to local storage. And convert it to Date object when you are fetching from local storage.**

LocalStorage only supports text. So it will always do **JSON.stringify** on your object before storing it.